# Cx_freeze excluding unwanted libs

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am trying to exluce a few libs that i do not need in my build but even when added to the list they are still shown in the build log.

this is my code for the build.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"excludes": ["tkinter", "PIL"], "include_files": 
['bin'], "optimize": 2}

setup(
    author="secret",
    name="app",
    options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    version="1.0",
    description="something",
    executables=[Executable("app.py", base="Console")])
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like it should work...have you checked if the setup.py is referred to correctly in your command line?
To exclude the libs you don't need, this is what I use:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os    

build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os",                                  
                                  'numpy'
                                  ],
                     "excludes": ["PyQt4",
                                  "PyQt5",
                                  'matplotlib',                                  
                                  ],
                     "includes":["pandas",
                                 ],                     
                     "include_files": [r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\tcl86t.dll',
                                       r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs\tk86t.dll',],
                     "optimize": 2,
                     }


base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

name = "yourscript.py"

setup(  name = name,
        version = "0.1",
        description = "My GUI application!",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable(name, base=base)])
```

This successfully excludes the big packages I don't use, so you could try modifying this.